# How to get order to go 1, 2, 3, 4... rather than 1, 10, 11, 12, 2, 3, 4

Tags: channel-entries, number-format, order-info

I'm sure this is a simple one, but it's got me stumped so I'd appreciate your thoughts. Here goes...

- I'm displaying a selection of images
- The order of these images is controlled by using orderby="file_index" & sort="asc" in the channel entries tag
- The file index field contains a number (i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc,), but is not changeable (i.e. we can't use two digit numbers for all images)
- The problem is that when there's more than ten images, they are being output as 1,10,11,12, 2, 3, 4... rather than 1, 2, 3, 4... In other words, the teens are being put before the 2

**Any ideas on how to make the images display in the correct order?**

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to that custom field settings (Edit Field) and select "Field Content" as "Number".